# If parameter-less case classes without parentheses are deprecated in Scala, why does Akka still allow them to be passed?

Tags: scala, akka, case-class

I spent two days trying to debug an issue where a message wasn't being handled by an actor, ultimately to find out the message being sent to it didn't have the parentheses following its name. If parameter-less case classes without parentheses are deprecated in Scala, why does Akka still allow them to be sent without warning?

Comment: A parameterless case class is really a `case object`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the problem here isn't that the companion object is not Serializable. You would get warning anyway - and an exception if you use akka remoting. The problem probably was that the receive function in the receieving actor doesn't have a case for the companion object.

Akka simply doesn't care which messages are you sending as you can send any object as a message. Doesn't make sense to me to have a check that you shouldn't be sending a deprecated class.

Comment: I was using a proxy for RabbitMQ in place of Akka's remoting, which masked the serializable issue. That would explain why I didn't see an exception. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing here but sounds like what you were sending was the companion object of the case class and not the case class itself. The case class would have been serializable by default (all case classes are serializable if constructed from serializable components) but the companion is not guaranteed to be serializable.